# DataGrid vertical scroll bar visible only when DataGrid is scrolled all the way to the right

Tags: java, gwt, datagrid, scrollpane

I have a FlexTable that houses a ScrollPane, which contains a DataGrid.
THe ScrollPane is set to a 100% width, 450px height. The DataGrid is set to 200% width, and 450px height.

The horizontal scroll bar allows me to scroll the table horizontally as expected. However, the vertical scroll bar that lets me scroll through different rows only is visible if I'm scrolled all the way to the right. Is there a way to change this behavior so that the vertical scroll bar is always visible on the right hand side, like in C#'s DataGrid, for example?

I'm looking at the API for DataGrid and do not see anything useful. I have alwaysShowScrolLBars set to true.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I shouldn't put a DataGrid inside a ScrollPane since GWT's DataGrid has scrolling built in. To get the desired scrolling behavior, i set the size of the data grid, and then teh size of the table (which is larger than the overall datagrid widget).

```
    // full width, 55% height
    int dataGridPixelHeight = (int) (Window.getClientHeight() * 0.55);      
    m_resultsDataGrid.setSize("100%", dataGridPixelHeight + "px");

    // sets the actual inner grid to be wide, allowing horizontal scroll
    m_resultsDataGrid.setTableWidth(200, Unit.PCT);
```